# Regex to get the session token value from the response

Tags: regex

I want to get the session token value from this json response:

```
{ "userId":1234, "role":"hello", "sessionToken":"91da56ba-ac18-409d-8de0-9ec944781b49",
  "showWelcomePage":gh, "accountType":0, "businessType":"Enterprise-Location",
  "accountCount":3, "accountId":null, "userOutputMessage":null, 
  "businessOutputMessage":null, "businessId":2345678ggt4, "business":null }
```

Comment: Why not just parse the json?  What programming language are you using?

Comment: trying to use it in zabbix the syntax of doing this is {sessiontoken}=regex:"regularexpression" and zabbix uses libcurl and follows posix

Comment: Checkout this tool: https://regexr.com/ . very helpful for experimenting with regex

Comment: @Jordan I have found [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) to be more useful and powerful than regexr.com. Check it out if you haven't.

Answer (score 3):

This matches the session token value:

```
(?<="sessionToken":")[^"]*
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/ARTgqMg3GU).

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<="sessionToken":")[^"]*
```

https://regexr.com/3r9b8

Comment: You can remove "session" from the expression since only "Token" is needed to find the lookbehind. `(?<=Token":").+(?=")`

Comment: not necessarily, there can be fields in json like authToken etc, so better match full word

Comment: The full JSON response is given, so there's no reason to assume an extra property will appear.